# error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`. in windows 10

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Hi I am very new and fresh to react native, I have followed docs installed all needed tools to run react-native with android studio.

Here is my sdk platform settings

[image]

Here is my sdk tools settings
[image]

I can launch the virtual device manually its shows up and working normally,

But When I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error

```
PS C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\shoppingList> react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 963 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

        at makeError (C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\shoppingList\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
        at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\shoppingList\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    PS C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\shoppingList>
```

what do I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the JAVA_HOME (And maybe some other variables) to the PATH.

First of all: locate your Java installation directory

> If you didn't change the path during installation, it'll be something
>   like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk[...]

If you didn't find it, try reinstalling the java JDK (You can find it [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)

Then do one of the following:

> `Windows 7:` Right click My Computer and select Properties > Advanced
>
> `Windows 8:` Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings
>
> `Windows 10:` Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the
>   system environment variables

Then:

Click the Environment Variables button.

Under System Variables, click New.

In the Variable Name field, enter `JAVA_HOME`

In the Variable Value field, enter your JDK installation path .

If the path contains spaces, use the shortened path name. For example, `C:\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`

[edit] i see you will need to install adb too

Download the ADB ZIP file for Windows, using [this](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip) link

Extract the contents of this ZIP file into an easily accessible folder (such as C:\adb)

Open Windows explorer and browse to where you extracted the contents of this ZIP file

Then open up a Command Prompt from the same directory as this ADB binary. This can be done by holding Shift and Right-clicking within the folder then click the “open command prompt here” option. (Some Windows 10 users may see “PowerShell” instead of “command prompt”.)install adb

Make sure to have an android emulator installed on your windows machine, propably you will use AVD, so open AVD Manager on the Android Studio Screen and create one (If you dont have one), then run it before running the `react-native run-ios` command